# Ensuring uniqueness in recursive query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a very basic parent-child / tree hierarchy and a recursive query that also adds `depth` and loads everything perfectly… almost. When I attempt to load several nodes, where one of them is a child of another, I get duplicate rows (because `depth` gets updated and rows are no longer identical).

I did read the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html), I am not using `UNION ALL`, I did try the `NOT cycle` trick from the documentation, I know about the [ltree](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ltree.html) data type, but I cannot use it. This is something else, consider the following tree:

```
5
├─9
│ └─15
├─10
│ └─16
└─11
  └─17
```

And the query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE "CTE" AS
(
    SELECT "id", 0 AS "depth"
    FROM "Node" WHERE "id" IN (5, 9, 15)
    UNION
    SELECT "Node"."id", "CTE"."depth" + 1
    FROM "CTE" JOIN "Node" ON "Node"."parentId" = "CTE"."id"
)
SELECT *
FROM "CTE"
ORDER BY "id";
```

Which results in:

```
id  depth 
5   0
9   0
9   1
10  1
11  1
15  0
15  1
15  2
16  2
17  2
```

Instead of the desired result:

```
id  depth 
5   0
9   0
10  1
11  1
15  0
16  2
17  2
```

Running the same query with `WHERE "id" = 5` produces this (note, how depth differs, because selection is made right from the root):

```
id  depth 
5   0
9   1
10  1
11  1
15  2
16  2
17  2
```

A solution to that would be to modify join to become:

```
FROM "CTE" JOIN "Node" ON 
    "Node"."parentId" = "CTE"."id" AND 
    "Node"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "id" FROM "CTE")
```

But Postgres doesn't allow referencing to the "CTE" from a subquery. I want to know if there's a proper approach to this problem?

**By the way**, I did come up with a solution that works, I tried it on several different scenarios, but I'm not 100% sure that it would work in all cases. It basically eliminates the initially selected values, ensuring that iteration won't "enter" them. Am I on the right foot with it / are there any pitfalls with this approach?

```
WITH RECURSIVE "CTE" AS
(
    SELECT "id", 0 AS "depth"
    FROM "Node" WHERE "id" IN (5, 9, 15)
    UNION
    SELECT "Node"."id", "CTE"."depth" + 1
    FROM "CTE" JOIN "Node" ON 
        "Node"."parentId" = "CTE"."id" 
        AND NOT IN (5, 9, 15)
)
SELECT *
FROM "CTE"
ORDER BY "id";
```

Comment: What exactly is the output you are looking for?

Comment: And what is so special about `"id" IN (5, 9, 15)` ? They constitute just one possible path in the tree.

Comment: Your query does exacly, what you asked: it returns a forest, with three root-nodes (5, 9, 15). But looking at your hierarchy, these nodes are not on the same level (that's why the duplicates exists: one for each tree in the forest). If you want to query the example tree only, you need `WHERE "id" = 5` only.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name apologies, added the expected output.

Comment: @wildplasser nothing special about it, it can be 5, 10 or any other set of nodes that contains elements from the same hierarchy branch.

Comment: @pozs I know what my query does, I described what's going wrong, and I know what I need, I'm not sure how to get it. You are not paying attention if you want to help. It must accept any set of id and return only those items and their children without duplicates (here duplicates = rows with the same ids).

Comment: @IanBytchek if you want only the descendants, just don't select a depth. `UNION` (without `ALL`) will select every node only once. But if you want depth too, the output above is completely logical: f.ex. `15` has a depth 2, from the root of `5`, it has a depth 1, from `9` and it has a depth 0, from itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Data
CREATE TABLE node
        ( id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , parentid integer REFERENCES node(id)
        );

INSERT INTO node(id,parentid) VALUES
(5, NULL)
, (9,5), (10,5), (11,5)
, (15,9), (16,10), (17,11)
        ;

-- query
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
    SELECT id, 0 AS depth
    FROM node WHERE id IN (5, 9, 15)
    UNION
    SELECT node.id, tree.depth + 1
    FROM tree JOIN node ON node.parentid = tree.id
    )
SELECT *
FROM tree tr
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( -- trivial way to suppress duplicates with longer path
        SELECT *
        FROM tree nx
        WHERE nx.id = tr.id
        AND nx.depth < tr.depth
        )
ORDER BY id
        ;
```

---

UPDATE: This looks less costly. It is correct for the given data (but not in the general case IIUC):

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
    SELECT id, 0 AS depth
    FROM node WHERE id IN (5, 9, 15)
    UNION
    SELECT node.id, tree.depth + 1
    FROM tree JOIN node ON node.parentid = tree.id
    WHERE node.id NOT IN (5, 9, 15)
    )
SELECT *
FROM tree tr
ORDER BY id
        ;
```

Comment: Wow, that's crazy! I didn't think of getting rid of duplicates outside the cte. Thanks!

Comment: Yes there is a strong tendency to prune in an earlier stage. (avoid them before you have to abort them ...)

Comment: I looked into filtering yesterday and didn't find anything what would solve this. I just checked `DISTINCT ON ("id")`, it does the job without a sub-query, `ORDER BY "id", "depth" DESC` makes it also sorted by max depth. I'll wait to see if anyone has any other ideas. Thanks though, you totally gave me the right idea!

Comment: I went for `DISTINCT ON` in the end. Thanks for the solution though!